# Can't find the bug in javascript

Tags: javascript

Code:

```
for(int j=0; j<virtualFields.length();j++)
{
    finalOptions += '<option value="'+virtualFields[j]+'"><\/option>' ;   
}
```

Firebug is giving this error:

> Missing ; after for loop initializer.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the best answer if one solves your problem :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Javascript doesn't understand `int`. Use `var` instead.

Some other pointers:

- Assuming `virtualFields` is an ordinary array, `length` is a property, not a method.
- You may need to html escape the `virtualFields[j]` values that you're concatenating like that.
- You only need to escape `/` inside a regular expression, not within an ordinary string. So `</option>` would work just fine.

(these points are not related to the error, but you may wish to take them into account anyway)

Comment: I do this mistake all the time myself. :)

Comment: Re escaping `/`: *some* HTML parsers think that *every* closing tag, i.e., everything that starts with `</`, is the closing tag of the `script` element. That's also why it is advised to either escape those tags appearing within strings in JavaScript, or split the string like this: `"<"+"/end>"`.

Comment: Marcel: That sounds interesting, I've never heard that before. Can you provide a reference? What browsers or parsers are you talking about?

Comment: And if you separate the `"</sc"+"ript>"` string it will trigger the `alert("hi");` http://jsfiddle.net/6QE56/1/

Comment: @BrunoLM: that's a `<script>` tag, I'm well aware that breaks. It's because once you open the tag, the HTML parser looks only for a closing `</script>` tag, ignoring everything else. It finds that "inside the JS string", but the parser won't care about whether it's in a string or not (it doesn't understand Javascript). The same thing does not happen with other closing tags, hence why I questioned Marcel's assertion that it happened for *every* closing tag.

Comment: Gijs, you should put an at-sign in front of my first name to let me know you replied to me (so I'll get notified).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure where I read it, neither do I know which browsers break, but it was said by someone who was very well into the language. And as it doesn't hurt, better save than be sorry.

Comment: @Marcel: Sorry, will try to be consistent about @. It's annoying that SO gives no feedback about it meaning anything. Regarding the issue... I suppose so. It seems extremely unlikely to me (but then, doesn't everything presented without evidence to a skeptical person ;-) ). Maybe, maybe, closing `</head>` (or `</body>`?) tags could do this, but otherwise... Regarding downsides, it hurts legibility. As for safe than sorry... that's why you run integration and functional tests in all the browsers you care about, right? ;-)

Comment: It's good to be skeptical, but there are a hell lot of browsers in the world I even don't know about. I don't care about browsers, I care about *people*, especially those who are visiting/using my sites and that might encounter errors. It's the same as those pesky semicolons: even if I knew the exact rules of automatic semicolon insertion by heart, I would put them after every statement, just to be sure. Better one needless time too many than one time too less (and yes, I walked into many holes before). And about `@`: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 0):

You are using `int` to declare a variable.

Use `var` instead.

Also, if `virtualFields` is an `Array`, you should just be accessing the `length` property, not as a method.